# Extracting Shapefile or geojson from ArcGIS web map

Tags: python, token, arcgis, scrape, esri

Need help! I am trying to get zoning by-law information as geojson or shapefile from this ArcGIS web map [site](https://maps1.brampton.ca/PlanningViewer/). Usually, the esri2geojson method would work fine 90% of the time even when there's a token involved. However, this web map seems to generate the token internally, thus no token could be found in the dev tools. I tried to generate my own token in order to access the [rest service](https://utility.arcgis.com/usrsvcs/servers/d1ef923eccd64eb18724d46734d52438/rest/services/COB/Zoning/MapServer/0) too, but it didn't work either. I was wondering if anyone would have any insights to any other methods where I can extract the information? Much thanks and appreciation in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was curious to take a look, and just noticed that the splash screen states:
"Data for the Brampton Planning Viewer can be downloaded from Brampton's Open Data portal, the GeoHub.", linking to https://geohub.brampton.ca/search?collection=Dataset.

Not sure of the exact dataset that you're after, but shouldn't give you any token difficulties - looks like the datasets are offered in various formats including geojson.

Comment: thanks for taking a look! ya unfortunately the open data/geohub doesn't contain the zoning bylaw data I need =(

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you reach out to their open data team. You were on the right track by looking for the REST service, but they clearly have that layer disabled for public consumption. This may be a simple oversight. In my state they are excellent about answer questions and requests
open@brampton.ca